# init.d script not working .... but the command works if I execute it in the console

Tags: linux, centos, scripting, inittab

I have a command that is working fine if I executed it from the command line ... but when I put it in an init.d script it wont's start (well .. it starts but have a behavior different from that when it is run directly).

Any idea why this is not working on the init script ?

The command is : `bluepill load /var/www/html/bluepill.conf`

And the init.d script is :

```
    #!/bin/sh

    ## Based on http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/feature/15380.html
    # chkconfig: 345 99 1
    # processname: solr
    # Provides: bluepill
    # Default-Start: 3 4 5
    # Default-Stop: 0 1 2 6
    # Short-Description: bluepill daemon, providing process monitoring
    # Description: Bluepill

    # Check for missing binaries
    BLUEPILL_BIN=/usr/local/bin/bluepill
    test -x $BLUEPILL_BIN || { echo "$BLUEPILL_BIN not installed";
            if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
            else exit 5; fi; }

    # Check for existence of needed config file and read it
    BLUEPILL_CONFIG=/var/www/html/bluepill.conf
    test -r $BLUEPILL_CONFIG || { echo "$BLUEPILL_CONFIG not existing";
            if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
            else exit 6; fi; }

    case "$1" in
      start)
        echo -n "Starting bluepill "
        $BLUEPILL_BIN load $BLUEPILL_CONFIG
        ;;
      stop)
        echo -n "Shutting down bluepill "
        $BLUEPILL_BIN quit
        ;;
      restart)
        ## Stop the service and regardless of whether it was
        ## running or not, start it again.
        $0 stop
        $0 start
      ;;
      *)
        ## If no parameters are given, print which are avaiable.
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
```

Update (to answer few questions) :

I also added the script in order to be executed at boot time using :

```
chkconfig --add bluepill_script  
chkconfig --level 345 bluepill_script  on
```

Comment: What happens when you run `<scriptname> start`?

Comment: when running service bluepill_script start it seems to work ... but not doing its job ... but when I stop it with service bluepill_script stop and then manually run the command : bluepill load /var/www/html/bluepill.conf it works fine !  .... I don't see where is the problem ... because the script is executing the same command ... can it be related to access privileges (even if I used chmod 777 for the script)?

Comment: post the output of "/bin/sh -x /etc/init.d/bluepill_script start"

Comment: Justin, when running : 
    /bin/sh -x /etc/init.d/bluepill_script start
I'm getting :

    + BLUEPILL_BIN=/usr/local/bin/bluepill
    + test -x /usr/local/bin/bluepill
    + BLUEPILL_CONFIG=/var/www/html/bluepill.conf
    + test -r /var/www/html/bluepill.conf
    + case "$1" in
    + echo -n 'Starting bluepill 'Starting bluepill + /usr/local/bin/bluepill load /var/www/html/bluepill.conf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try adding

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

to the top of the init script.

Comment: Justin, why this is needed to be in the script ?

Comment: because /usr/local/bin/bluepill is likely trying to start more programs located in /usr/local, which it is unable to find.  /usr/local/bin/bluepill might be a shell script, you can try reading it.

Answer (score 1):

I'll echo Kamil's call for output when run.

Furthermore, have you tried `chkconfig --add bluepill` and `chkconfig bluepill on`.

Otherwise, I'm betting it's some sort of environment variable in the script.  Try sourcing an environment at the start via `. /etc/profile` or the like.  Especially since this looks like it's installed in /usr/local/bin.  It may need PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH set properly.

Comment: As I said in a response to Kamil Kisiel's comment, even after the server is started ... when I try service bluepill_script start it seems to work (no error is displayed) but it's not doing its job

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following init.d script, and was having a similar problem because the bluepill gem was installed under an rvm installation.  Notice having to source either the rvm environment variable, but the same could have been achieved by sourcing /etc/profile (since it's also being set there).  I'm using an Opscode cookbook recipe to set these, so those paths are set to be variable given where the rvm cookbook is installing its gems.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Bluepill
#
# chkconfig: - 85 15
# description: start, stop, restart bluepill
#

RETVAL=0

if [[ -s /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm ]] ; then source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm ; fi

case "$1" in
    start)
      for i in /etc/bluepill/*.pill; do
        /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bluepill load $i
      done
      RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    stop)
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bluepill stop
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bluepill quit
      RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    restart)
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bluepill restart
      RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    status)
      /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/bluepill status
      RETVAL=$?
  ;;
    *)
      echo "Usage: bluepill {start|stop|restart|status}"
      exit 1
  ;;
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

Answer (score 0):

ok.. dumb question but did you set the script to start at bootup? I'm more familiar with debian style distros but ntsysv or chkconfig might be what you need.

Comment: yes ... see the update

Answer (score 0):

Another dumb question, is bluepill loaded in memory after the script is run? `ps -ef | grep bluepill`

Answer (score 0):

The lack of errors in the log is no clear indication that the init script is working. Two simple steps will debug this.

1. Add some debugging details inside the script. I like to write the line number to a log file from various points with the script. No output? Then it's almost certainly not being run.
2. Ensure the script has in fact been enabled to run when you think it has, as several others have already stated. If it's not being run that could account for the lack of error messages in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

you might also have to put a link in one of the /etc/rcX-folders (depending on your intended runlevel) and run

> sudo run update-rc.d SkriptnameWithinInitDWithoutPath defaults